# Deleting appointments from shared Outlook calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to clear a shared calendar.

I have a delete method that works in my Outlook calendar however it doesn't clear the shared calendar.

```
Private Sub DeleteAllAppointments()
    Dim olkApp As Object, _
        olkSession As Object, _
        olkCalendar As Object, _
        olkItem As Object, _
        intIndex As Integer
    Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olkSession = olkApp.Session
    olkSession.Logon

    Set olkCalendar = olkSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    For intIndex = olkCalendar.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olkItem = olkCalendar.Items.Item(intIndex)
        olkItem.Delete
    Next
    Set olkItem = Nothing
    Set olkCalendar = Nothing
    olkSession.Logoff
    Set olkSession = Nothing
    Set olkApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is where the method fails

```
Set olkCalendar = olkSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
```

Is this is a folder path issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it.

```
Sub Delete_SharedCal_History()
    DeleteCal_Appts "Office Calendar", "1/9/2001", "0:00:01", "12/31/2013", "23:59:59"
End Sub

Sub DeleteCal_Appts(sCalendarName As String, ap_dateStart As String, ap_startTime As String, ap_dateEnd As String, ap_endTime As String)
'   Specified Shared Calendar - Delete all events in specified Date Range
'   Author: Frank Zakikian
    Dim objAppointment As AppointmentItem
    Dim objAppointments As Items
    Dim objNameSpace As NameSpace
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Dim nInc As Integer
    Dim sFilter As Variant
    Dim dtStartTime As Date, dtEndTime As Date
    dtStartTime = CDate(ap_dateStart & " " & ap_timeStart)
    dtEndTime = CDate(ap_dateEnd & " " & ap_timeEnd)

    Set objNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'next line would be for use of personal calendar object..
    'Set objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set objRecip = objNameSpace.CreateRecipient(sCalendarName)
    objRecip.Resolve
    'Debug.Print objRec.AddressEntry
    Set objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Akron Chambers Calendar"), olFolderCalendar).Items

    sFilter = "[Start] > '" & Format(dtStartTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & _
      "' And [Start] < '" & Format(dtEndTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
    objAppointments.Sort "[Start]", False
    Debug.Print "Total Items at begin: " & objAppointments.Count 'dev. fyi
    Set objAppointment = objAppointments.Find(sFilter)
    While TypeName(objAppointment) <> "Nothing"
        'If MsgBox(objAppointment.Subject & vbCrLf & "Delete " & objRec.AddressEntry & " item now? ", vbYesNo, "Delete Calendar Item") = vbYes Then
            objAppointment.Delete
            nInc = nInc + 1
        'End If
        Set objAppointment = objAppointments.FindNext
    Wend
    MsgBox "Deleted " & nInc & " calendar items.", vbInformation, "Delete done"
    Debug.Print "Total Items at finish: " & objAppointments.Count 'dev. fyi
    Set objAppointment = Nothing
    Set objAppointments = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`olkSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)` would retrieve your default Calendar folder. You need to either use `olkSession.GetSharedDefaultFolder(someRecipient, olFolderCalendar)` (where `someRecipient` is returned by `olkSession.CreateRecipient)` or open the appropriate store from the Namespace.Stores collection (assuming the delegate mailbox is already there) and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder`.